# Running USB cable lengths of 30 feet

Tags: usb, audio, microphone

I have a USB mic and would like to record from in a padded closet roughly 30 feet away from the computer.

I read that buying a 30ft cable will not work, but is there anyway around this?

According to Wikipedia: USB 2.0 provides for a maximum cable length of 5 meters for devices running at Hi Speed (480 Mbit/s). The primary reason for this limit is the maximum allowed round-trip delay of about 1.5 μs.

So how do these USB cable extenders work then? Will one of these extenders work with my USB mic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a usb extension should work.

USB Extender/Repeater:

http://www.usbgear.com/AB30FT-AAC.html

http://www.usbcables.com/Extension_cable_USB_15ft/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Make sure whatever you buy says "active repeater" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think a mic really needs full 480 Mbit/s transfer rates, however the delay is a factor. Considering a powered USB extension cable [only costs $8.50 plus shipping](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=103&cp_id=10303&cs_id=1030312&p_id=6149&seq=1&format=2) I would just say go ahead and try it and report back.

---

Make sure whatever you get is called either Active or Powered, it basically acts as a 1 port USB hub.

Comment: If the delay turn out to be a problem you can use a 'USB mic with build in sound card'  (e.g. a blue yeti, though I am reluctant to mention what seems like shopping advice. It is just the Mic I looked at a while ago)